# Large BF-value in two-way within-subject ANOVA but non-significant interaction using frequentist approach

Tags: r, bayesian, anova, p-value

A two-way within-subject ANOVA revealed a non-significant interaction (p = .067).  A Bayesian analysis conducted using `anovaBF()` in R on the same data revealed extreme evidence against the null (BF = 110622).  Is this possible?

Edit:

Priors were computed based on Rouder et al. (2012).

The same Bayesian analysis conducted on response time data revealed normal BF-values and abnormal (above) BF-values for the error percentage data.

I suspect the BF-values of the error percentage data are erroneous since they are not normally distributed (i.e., a high proportion of cells containing 0% errors in the sample).

Comment: It could mean that your prior is driving the Bayes factor. It might help to post more details, including particular hypotheses and prior distributions.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. You can't use ANOVA for percentage correct data, since this data can severely violate ANOVA's assumptions. Depending on how badly your data violates these assumptions, you could end up with any results at all! It would be easier to answer the question if you could include some plots of your data, summary statistics, and the F statistics from the ANOVA.